# Does lcov generate intermediate .gcov files?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang, gcov, lcov

I use **lcov** with an Objective-C project and the [XcodeCoverage](https://github.com/jonreid/XcodeCoverage) scripts and I get a nice html report on my code coverage.

However I would like to "keep" the intermediate `.gcov` files (if any) to feed them to another tool.
Something similar to the `--keep` option of **gcovr**. Does **lcov** provides such an option ? Is it generating any intermediate `.gcov` files at all ?

I'm sure it's something obvious that I missed in the docs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, **lcov** generates `.gcov` files but they are deleted once they have been processed. There is no "keep" option.

I found in the code of version lcov-1.10 the following behavior:
**lcov** calls **geninfo** which removes the `.gcov` files after processing.